# Is it possible to determine which control has focus while in a code break?

Tags: c#, asp.net

As I'm stepping through code, I want to know which control has the focus.  Is there any way to do this in the Immediate window while the code is being stepped through?

I'm running an ASP page on an Intranet. The cursor is ending up somewhere in limbo and I can't figure out what control has it. There are a few hidden textboxes laying on top of each other. Was hoping there was some quick and easy way instead of having to make all my controls unhidden, as I'm not even sure if that's the cause.

Comment: Debugger break? i think it is not possible to determine that coz it is in the page lifecyle process in asp.net.

Comment: Unless you check all the controls `Focus` property, I believe.

Comment: What type of app? Winforms, WPF?

Comment: @DaveMackersie, isn't it clearly tagged as `ASP.NET`?

Comment: Running an ASP page on an Intranet.  The cursor is ending up somewhere in limbo and I can't figure out what control has it.  There are a few hidden textboxes laying on top of each other.  Was hoping there was some quick and easy way instead of having to make all my controls unhidden.

Comment: @Rahul there is no real controls if OP debugging C# portion of ASP.Net.

Comment: @JohnnyBones would you mind actually updating the post?

Comment: Couldn't you use focus manager to get the current [focused element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms604088%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and store it in a variable right before you break? That way it will be easier to check the variables contents for the focused element.

Answer (score 0):

So, each control will have a tabindex property, if you are debugging and use the stepin when each control is loading you can see the tabindex property in the code.  You can hasten this process by figuring out what object you are tabbing out of when it breaks.